# ¿Cómo se dice: "los días domingo" o "los días domingos"?

Tags: gramática, plurales, hispanoamérica, número-gramatical

Después de releer [Why do they say 'un día domingo' in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/15931/6915) y de investigar un poco, entendí que preceder la palabra "día" a "lunes", "martes", etc. es un arcaísmo frecuente en latinoamérica. Yo lo uso habitualmente, digo *la reunión será el día jueves*. Según veo, no es habitual en España.

Por ser un sustantivo, el plural de un día termina en -s, lo cual normalmente se camufla, excepto en los últimos dos días de la semana:

> el lunes - los lunes
>
> el miércoles - los miércoles
>
> el sábado - los sábado**s**
>
> el domingo - los domingo**s**

¿Cómo se debería decir correctamente cuando se usa la palabra "día" en plural?:

> Nos reuniremos los días domingo

o

> Nos reuniremos los días domingos

Comment: Encontré lo siguiente nomás de chiripada: http://hispanoteca.eu/Foro-preguntas/ARCHIVO-Foro/Plural-d%C3%ADas%20semana.htm

Comment: ¿Podría ser este un caso similar al de los "[países miembro](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17474/12637)"?

Comment: @CarlosAlejo Creo que si, tal como lo explica la [RAE aquí](http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas) pero sólo si fuera correcto adicionar la palabra "días" Según el enlace de aparente001 es incorrecto y debe evitarse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resumen**: atendiendo al uso actual y a lo que dice el DPD, **es correcto decir "días sábados", "días domingos"**.

---

#### Un poco de historia

**En latín, los días sí que se indicaban anteponiendo la palabra "día"**: [*dies Lunae*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies_Lunae), [*dies Martis*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies_Martis), ..., [*dies Sabbati*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies_Sabbati#Latin), *dies {[Dominicus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies_Dominicus) ~ [Dominica](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dies_Dominica#Latin)}*.

En casi todos los casos, **el nombre de cada día particular** (*Martis*, *Sabbati*...) **se tomaba del genitivo** del nombre de aquello a lo que estaba dedicado, y **se decía igual en singular que en plural**: por ejemplo, el genitivo de *Sabbatum* ("Sabbath") es *Sabbati* que quiere decir "del Sabbath", y tanto en singular ("día del Sabbath") como en plural ("días del Sabbath") se escribe igual.

La única salvedad es la del propio domingo.
Resulta que *Dominicus* no es un nombre, sino una expresión que ya de por sí quiere decir "del Señor", y usar el genitivo sería redundante (como decir "día de del Señor").
Por este motivo, ***dies Dominicus* era el único de los días que sí cambiaba entre singular y plural**. Sin ir más lejos, el acusativo (el caso latino de donde toman su origen muchas palabras en español) sería *diem Dominicum* en singular y *dies Dominicos* en plural.

Todo eso para el latín. Pero **¿qué hizo el español con estos usos?**

#### En español

Sabemos que al español los nombres de los días han llegado como "lunes", "martes", ..., "sábado", "domingo" precisamente desde las expresiones latinas arriba indicadas.
Se podría pensar que, al principio, lo normal habría sido que todos los días cuyo nombre venía del genitivo, se quedasen siempre en singular, i. e. "día(s) lunes", "día(s) martes", ..., "día(s) sábado"; siendo el domingo el único que, quizá, se podría encontrar tanto en singular como en plural.

Un par de consultas en el CORDE para encontrar los usos anteriores a 1700 podría confirmar esto: hay una coincidencia para "días domingos" en el s. XVI, y otra para "días domingo" en el s. XVII; aunque ninguna para "días sábado" ni "días sábados" (tampoco con "sabbado").

#### Uso actual

Pero hoy en día no es así. Lo cierto es que, a lo largo de los siglos de evolución del español, **el uso del genitivo latino para singular y plural se perdió, y los nombres de los días pasaron a ser palabras normales y corrientes que formaban su plural igual que las demás**: añadiendo -s.

Sin embargo, **si consultamos en [CORDE](http://corpus.rae.es/cordenet.html) los usos actuales** (entre 1800 y 2000), podremos ver que **predomina con claridad el uso en plural "días domingos" y "días sábados"** (10 y 4 ocurrencias respectivamente) sobre el uso en singular "días domingo" y "días sábado" (2 y 1 ocurrencias solamente).

Por último, atendiendo a [lo que dice el DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i#24):

> **2.4. Unidades léxicas formadas por dos sustantivos**. En las construcciones nominales formadas por dos sustantivos, de los que el segundo actúa como modificador del primero, solo el primer sustantivo lleva marca de plural (...) Pero si el segundo sustantivo puede funcionar, con el mismo valor, como atributo del primero en oraciones copulativas, tiende a tomar también la marca de plural: *Estados miembros, países satélites, empresas líderes, palabras claves* (pues puede decirse *Estos estados son miembros de la UE; Esos países fueron satélites de la Unión Soviética; Esas empresas son líderes en su sector; Estas palabras son claves para entender el asunto*).

**Decir "días sábados", "días domingos" sería correcto**, ya que si bien es cierto que la expresión "días domingos" está compuesta de dos sustantivos, igualmente se podría decir "estos días fueron domingos", con lo cual entraría en el segundo supuesto.

#### ¿Pero acaso es correcto lo de anteponer "día"?

El DPD lo recoge, y no dice que sea incorrecto:

> **[días de la semana](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=semana)**.
> 3. En el español americano es bastante frecuente que aparezcan en aposición a la palabra *día*, uso normal en el español medieval y clásico del que también quedan restos en algunas zonas de España: *«Aquella fue mi última conversación con ella, el día miércoles de la semana pasada»* (Serrano Corazón [Chile 2001]); *«Esta romería se ha celebrado el día lunes de Pascua de Pentecostés»* (DNavarra [Esp.] 20.5.99).

Answer (score 4):

En España, no digo en latinoamérica, no se utiliza la expresión:
"Nos reuniremos los días domingos" ni tampoco "Nos reuniremos los días domingo"

Creo que en latino-américa la expresión correcta sería:

```
"Nos reuniremos los días domingo"
```

En España simplemente se dice:

```
"Nos reuniremos los domingos"
```

Esta expresión indica directamente que nos vamos a reunir todos los días que sea domingo.

> En las construcciones formadas por **dos sustantivos que constituyen
>   una unidad léxica**, en las que el segundo de ellos modifica al
>   primero como si se tratara de un adjetivo, **normalmente solo el
>   primer sustantivo lleva marca de plural**

[Fuente](http://www.rae.es/consultas/palabras-clave-o-palabras-claves-copias-pirata-o-copias-piratas)